# Как реализовать подобный интерфейс

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Какими компонентами можно реализовать подобный интерфейс и какие свойства этих компонентов использовать? Прежде всего интересует реализация возможности развернуть/ свернуть компонент, чтобы показать/скрыть допконтент?

**Раскрыть**: [image: Раскрыть]
**Скрыть**: [image: Скрыть]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это CoordinatorLayout c

1. AppBarLayout c

   1. CollapsingToolbarLayout c

      1. Toolbar
      2. Пара TextView
2. NestedScrollView c

   1. LinearLayout в вертикальной ориентации с

      1. Куча вьюшек, включая раскрывающийся элемент (см. ниже)
3. FloatingActionButton

Раскрывающийся элемент делается так:

1. Составляете разметку в раскрытом виде.
2. Устанавливаете `android:visibility="gone"` всем элементам кроме тех, которые в свёрнутом виде
3. Вешаете слушатель нажатия на что-то и в нём меняете туда-обратно видимость нужных элементов.

Стандартного виджета для сего нет.